why are the values printed out not the values i requested from the list
I am making a the start of a poker based game. all it dose so far is draw 7 cards then allow the player to either discard the cards or play the cards.
My current problem happens when I try to play the cards. i ask it to play cards 4567 in my hand and instead it plays cards 2345. me and a friend have been starring at it for a while and we cant figure it out.
This is the function that is asking which cards to play and then playing them.
def phase1(deck,hand):
    InPlay = []
    DorP = input("discard or play: enter D or P:  ")

    if DorP == "D":
        discard = input("enter the cards to discard: e.g. 1267:   ")
        splitD = [int(i) - 1 for i in list(discard)]  # Convert to zero-based index
        splitD.sort(reverse=True)  # Sort indices in reverse order

        for num in splitD:
            hand.pop(num)

    if DorP == "P":
        ToPlay = input("enter the cards to play: e.g. 1267:   ")
        splitP = [int(i) - 1 for i in list(ToPlay)]  # Convert to zero-based index
        splitP.sort(reverse=True)  # Sort indices in reverse order

        for num in splitP:
            InPlay.append(hand[num])  # Add card to InPlay
            hand.pop(num)  # Remove card from deck

    
        print("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("In Play:", InPlay)

however i cannot find an error in this code so this is the rest of the code in case the error is elsewhere
import random

deck = ["Ace spades", "2 spades", "3 spades", "4 spades", "5 spades", "6 spades", "7 spades", "8 spades", "9 spades","10 spades", "Jack spades", "Queen spades", "King spades", "Ace clubs", "2 clubs", "3 clubs", "4 clubs", "5 clubs", "6 clubs", "7 clubs", "8 clubs", "9 clubs", "10 clubs", "Jack clubs", "Queen clubs", "King clubs", "Ace hearts", "2 hearts", "3 hearts", "4 hearts", "5 hearts", "6 hearts", "7 hearts", "8 hearts", "9 hearts","10 hearts", "Jack hearts", "Queen hearts", "King hearts", "Ace diamonds", "2 diamonds", "3 diamonds", "4 diamonds","5 diamonds", "6 diamonds", "7 diamonds", "8 diamonds", "9 diamonds", "10 diamonds", "Jack diamonds", "Queen diamonds",
"King diamonds"]

InPlay = []
hand = []
stop = False

def shuffle(deck):
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(deck)):
        num = random.randint(0,len(deck)-1)
        temp.append(deck[num])
        deck.pop(num)
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        deck.append(temp[i])
    temp = []

def draw(deck,hand):
    temp = []
    nums = []
    aces = []  # To store aces separately

    # Extract the first 7 cards
    for i in range(-(len(hand)-7)):
        hand.append(deck.pop(0))  # Always pop the first card in the remaining deck
    
    for card in hand:
        rank = card.split()[0]
        if rank == "Ace":
            aces.append(card)  # Separate Aces into the aces list
        elif rank.isdigit():
            nums.append((int(rank), card))  # Store as tuple (rank, card)
        elif rank == "Jack":
            nums.append((11, card))
        elif rank == "Queen":
            nums.append((12, card))
        elif rank == "King":
            nums.append((13, card))

    # Sort the numeric cards in descending order
    nums.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[0])

    hand = []

    # Add aces first, then the sorted numeric cards
    hand.extend(aces)
    hand.extend([card for _, card in nums])

    print("hand:", hand)

def phase1(deck,hand):
    InPlay = []
    DorP = input("discard or play: enter D or P:  ")

    if DorP == "D":
        discard = input("enter the cards to discard: e.g. 1267:   ")
        splitD = [int(i) - 1 for i in list(discard)]  # Convert to zero-based index
        splitD.sort(reverse=True)  # Sort indices in reverse order

        for num in splitD:
            hand.pop(num)

    if DorP == "P":
        ToPlay = input("enter the cards to play: e.g. 1267:   ")
        splitP = [int(i) - 1 for i in list(ToPlay)]  # Convert to zero-based index
        splitP.sort(reverse=True)  # Sort indices in reverse order

        for num in splitP:
            InPlay.append(hand[num])  # Add card to InPlay
            hand.pop(num)  # Remove card from deck

    
        print("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("In Play:", InPlay)
    
for i in range(0,3):
        print()
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
shuffle(deck)
draw(deck,hand)
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n")

while stop == False:
    phase1(deck,hand)
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n")

If I input cards to play it seemingly plays a random card.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hand: ['King clubs', '10 spades', '9 spades', '8 clubs', '7 hearts', '4 clubs', '3 spades']
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

discard or play: enter D or P:  P
enter the cards to play: e.g. 1267:   1

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In Play: ['4 clubs']
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hand: ['King clubs', '10 spades', '9 spades', '8 clubs', '7 hearts', '7 clubs', '3 spades']
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
discard or play: enter D or P:  P
enter the cards to play: e.g. 1267:   1

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In Play: ['3 spades']
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


"me and a friend have been starring at it for a while and we cant figure it out." Have you tried running the code with your debugger and stepping line by line through it instead? I get NameError: name 'check_play' is not defined.

draw() has its own local hand list, it's not the same as the one that you're passing to phase1().

@jabaa apologies that is a function later in the code that isn't relevant to this question. I forgot to delete that line.

when in doubt, add print-statements everywhere. E.g. if you add print("hand:", hand) at the start of phase1(), you'll see it looks different to at the end of draw()

Why do you need a separate aces list? Why not just use (14, card) for aces?

@Barmar That is a good point. and to as to why I didn't use 14 it is because I a not very bright. I just thought ace = 1 so therefor needs to be sorted differently.

@GeorgeRichards "not very bright"--don't be hard on yourself! Handling 'exception cases' like Aces in poker is a huge part of programming, and there's often trade-offs to however you decide to handle them. (e.g., you can treat them as 14 for sorting, but for detecting straights, they need to be either a 1 or a 14.) The only way you get better is through practice. And usually "practice" means doing it the hard way at first and then realizing there might have been a better way to do it.

The problem is with this line in draw():
hand = []

Now the hand variable no longer refers to the list that was passed in as a parameter. The caller's list is still the one that was updated in the earlier loop with hand.append(deck.pop(0)).
You should use a local variable for the unsorted hand (you defined the variable temp, but never used it, so I'm using that), then modify the caller's hand in place at the end.
def draw(deck,hand):
    temp = []
    nums = []
    aces = []  # To store aces separately

    # Extract the first 7 cards
    for i in range(-(len(hand)-7)):
        temp.append(deck.pop(0))  # Always pop the first card in the remaining deck
    
    for card in temp:
        rank = card.split()[0]
        if rank == "Ace":
            aces.append(card)  # Separate Aces into the aces list
        elif rank.isdigit():
            nums.append((int(rank), card))  # Store as tuple (rank, card)
        elif rank == "Jack":
            nums.append((11, card))
        elif rank == "Queen":
            nums.append((12, card))
        elif rank == "King":
            nums.append((13, card))

    # Sort the numeric cards in descending order
    nums.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[0])

    # Add aces first, then the sorted numeric cards
    hand.extend(aces)
    hand.extend([card for _, card in nums])

    print("hand:", hand)

BTW, the loop to extract the first 7 cards can be replaced with a slice:
temp = hand[:7]


thankyou four your help

temp was there because i previously did do it like you suggested using temp then adding it to hand. however this means that after I draw more cards in the same game the hand becomes unsorted. i thought that if I just made it append to hand and then sort it it would fix my problem but it somehow broke the code

You should probably split this into two functions. One for drawing cards and adding to the hand, another for sorting the hand and displaying it.

thx for the advice, I will do this.
